# Avoid strange letters in PHP? уникум

Tags: php

I try to avoid in person name some strange letters in PHP like:

```
уникум ник ник
```

Some ideas how can I avoid this in a input using preg_match?

Comment: Do you only want to allow latin characters?

Comment: How are these strange, it is just from the cyrillic alphabet. Quick search on "php only allow latin characters" turned up sites like [this](http://brugbart.com/allow-certain-characters-php)

Comment: You can add this to your html form: `<p>No Russians allowed</p>`, or try this: http://mamchenkov.net/wordpress/2011/08/18/php-regular-expression-to-match-englishlatin-characters-only/

Comment: hahah thank you friends!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you have PHP 5.1+ installed on your server, you can search for a specific unicode character properties.

See [the unicode character properties reference](http://php.net/manual/en/regexp.reference.unicode.php) in PHP manual.

For example, to disallow cyrillic aplhabet, you can test for:

```
preg_match("/\p{Cyrillic}/imu", $input, $matches) > 0
```

and return the error otherwise.

If you want to disallow **any** letters from outside latin character set, you can make test like that:

```
preg_match("/([^\p{Latin}\s0-9\W])/imu", $input) > 0
```

You should experiment with these to allow all needed punctation etc.

In the second example you can allow for several character sets. Following example allows standard latin along with hiragana characters.

```
preg_match("/([^\p{Latin}\p{Hiragana}\s0-9\W])/imu", $input) > 0
```

If you want to disallow anything which is not in a-z range (without accents etc), for example in usernames, the expression is even simplier:

```
preg_match("/([^a-zA-Z])/imu", $input) > 0
```

You have to be carefull with disallowing anything which is a valid unicode letter, though. You can eaisly annoy your users.

Answer (score 1):

Use a regular expression to only allow the character you want.

Example:

```
[A-Za-b]
```

Would only allow A to Z and a-z user names.
Here are some references:

[preg_match](http://php.net/manual/en/function.preg-match.php)

[Regular expression in PHP](http://www.tutorialspoint.com/php/php_regular_expression.htm)

This should get you started.

Below is a quick example

```
$subject = "ANDRE";
print preg_match('/^[A-Z]*$/', $subject) ? "It matches" : "It does not match!";
```

Pattern above only accepts capital letter from A to Z